# REACT Styling Issue

Tags: reactjs, sass

I am writing a REACT app that is a SharePoint online app that uses SASS.  The wizard I used to generate the app created a SASS file that imports Microsoft Fabric.  The file is named "PaymentForm.module.scss". I can adjust the styles that were created by the wizard in there and it works fine.  However, when I try adding a custom style/class to the file it doesn't work.  For example when I change the .container style its reflected in the app.  However, I added a "help-block style and added it to the txs file.  This does not work:

```css
.PaymentForm {
  .container {
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 25px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  .help-block {
    color: #e6003e;
  }
```

```
          <div className="help-block">
            Name on Card is required
          </div>
```

When I check the source from the browser.  One thing I noticed is the class names that were generated through the wizard do not have single quotes around them.  The class I created does so I'm thinking that's why its not working:

```css
require("./PaymentForm.module.css");
const styles = {
  PaymentForm: 'PaymentForm_25a72c53',
  container: 'container_25a72c53',
  'help-block': 'help-block_25a72c53',
  'ms-u-sm3': 'ms-u-sm3_25a72c53',
  'css-yk16xz-control': 'css-yk16xz-control_25a72c53',
  row: 'row_25a72c53',
  column: 'column_25a72c53',
  'ms-Grid': 'ms-Grid_25a72c53',
  title: 'title_25a72c53',
  subTitle: 'subTitle_25a72c53',
  description: 'description_25a72c53',
  button: 'button_25a72c53',
  label: 'label_25a72c53',
  'Select-control': 'Select-control_25a72c53'
};
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had to reference the style in my tsx like:
<div className={styles['help-block']}>
Name on Card is required